# Why do I get 'WebSocket opening handshake was canceled' trying to connect with JSSip?

Tags: javascript, sip, voip, jssip

I am trying to establish connection with JSSip with an already running SIP server. I have followed the documentation and came up with the following code. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body></body>

    <script src="jssip-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    var socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://sip.group.com');
    var configuration = {
        sockets  : [ socket ],
        uri      : 'sip:4051@sip.group.com',
        password : 'password#'
    };

    var coolPhone = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);

    coolPhone.start();

    // Register callbacks to desired call events
    var eventHandlers = {
      'progress': function(e) {
        console.log('call is in progress');
      },
      'failed': function(e) {
        console.log('call failed with cause: '+ e.data.cause);
      },
      'ended': function(e) {
        console.log('call ended with cause: '+ e.data.cause);
      },
      'confirmed': function(e) {
        console.log('call confirmed');
      }
    };

    var options = {
      'eventHandlers'    : eventHandlers,
      'mediaConstraints' : { 'audio': true, 'video': true }
    };

    var session = coolPhone.call('sip:4050@sip.group.com', options);
    </script>
</html>
```

My extension from the server is 4051 and I'm trying to make a call to 4050 my colleague. However, if I open the console of Chrome I see the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://sip.group.com/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

Comment: can you try it using `ws://` and see if it works?

Comment: I did. And now it shows this error: `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403`.

Comment: Do I have to run the HTML file through a server or just double clicking the file is enough to establish connection?

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue with jsSIP or web socket. Your sip.group.com wss is not accepting new connection and there is no sign of websocket in response when you try `https://sip.group.com/`

```
Connection:close
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:text/plain
Server:RTC/7.0
X-MS-Server-Fqdn:PNQIN100EDG02.infra.lync.com
```

1. Are your sure your wss is running in 443?
 if its running in different port then connect it using `wss://sip.group.com:port`